# Increase ASC limit clause for search results

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I would like to be able to list 1000 results, however I am being limited to 20 due to the ASC Limit with the gem thinking sphinx.

How can I increase the ASC Limit 0, 20 to 0, 1000?

```
SELECT GEODIST(0.5904448859496816, -1.464156709498043, latitude, longitude) AS geodist, * 
FROM `location_core` 
WHERE `geodist` BETWEEN 0.0 AND 200000.0 AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 
ORDER BY `geodist` ASC 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Is this something I have to modify with MYSQL?

controller:

```
  def index
       location  = Location.find_by_zipcode params[:zipcode] 
        latitude  = location.latitude * Math::PI / 180 
        longitude = location.longitude * Math::PI / 180 

        location_ids = Location.search_for_ids( 
          :geo   => [latitude, longitude], 
          :with  => {:geodist => 0.0..200_000.0}
        ) 
        @users = User.where(:location_id => location_ids)        
      end
```

Comment: Do you have the order and limit set on on your model's default scope? I don't see you setting the order and limit in controller

Comment: My scope from the Location model is `scope :by_zip_code, ->(zipcode) { where('zipcode = ?', zipcode) }`

Comment: We need to see the method definition for Location.search_for_ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASC 0,20 is fine.

Change

```
 :geo   => [latitude, longitude], 
          :with  => {:geodist => 0.0..200_000.0}
```

to

```
  :geo   => [latitude, longitude], 
  :with  => {:geodist => 0.0..200_000.0}, 
  :per_page => 1_000
```